# QuickBlox Swift Error QBRequest.logInWithUserLogin unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: swift, quickblox

I'm facing a weird issue called **unrecognized selector sent to class** when we call `QBRequest.logInWithUserLogin`. Please Help

```
var qbrequest:QBRequest = QBRequest.logInWithUserLogin("shaggy", password: "shaggy",
        successBlock: { (responseObject,user) -> Void in
          print(user)
        },

        errorBlock: {(error) -> Void in
            print("Failure")
        })
```

Comment: Hello! Have you correctly setup SDK using this instruction http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework#Framework ?
Step 6 & 7

Comment: Yes. I have correctly managed to add libraries and had  followed the steps.

Comment: Can you please provide a full crash log for this, including name of the unrecognized selector.

Comment: Hi! Was able to solve the above issue, but now I'm facing another issue while creating session **var user:QBUUser = QBUUser()
        user.ID = 7593145 var session:QBRTCSession  = QBRTCClient.instance().createNewSessionWithOpponents(NSArray(array: [user]) as [AnyObject] , withConferenceType:QBConferenceType.Video)**. It is giving runtime error  **saying unrecognized selector sent to instance 
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[QBChat isLoggedIn]: unrecognized selector sent to instance **. Sorry Im new to stackover flow.Please Help